# Need help for a getInput function

Tags: javascript, html, web

I've been having trouble with my javascript code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>js-game</title>
        <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="story.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="game">
            <ul id="output">
                <li onclick="main()">Click here to start!</li>
            </ul>
            <input autofocus id="inputLine" type="text">
            <p onclick="" id="enterInput">ENTER</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>



// Variables
var log="<li>Hello</li>";
var lastVar="";

// Functions
function getInput() {
    document.getElementById("enterInput").addEventListener("click", function() {
        return document.getElementById("inputLine").value;
        document.getElementById("inputline").value="";
    });
}
function output(output) {
    log=log + "<li>" + output + "</li>";
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=log;
}
function main() {
    output("What's your name?");
    alert(getInput());
}
```

As you can probably see I want to get input from a `<input type="text">` with the id of `inputLine`. And a button with the id of `enterInput`.

But all I get back is undefined, and I've been working on this for a long time, so I'm getting frustrated.

Sorry for bad english.

Comment: Can we see the HTML?

Comment: your line where you are setting the `.value` wont ever be reached as you are doing a return statement before it, also event callbacks do not return to anything

Comment: This won't work because you can't use `return` like that. Specifically, you can't make the interpreter stall until the button is clicked and there is input. Maybe you want a promise or something?

Comment: I think you should add the `click` eventListener with the function `getInput`

Comment: Can we see the rest of the JS? As far as I know 'getInput()' is never called.

Comment: Your stuff is ordered funny--the `getInput()` function is not getting the input, it is only adding an event listener to the `enterInput` element.

Comment: @mathiaskiær edit your answer and paste your code there for readability

Comment: So i should move the eventListener out of the function?

Comment: Based on what I can see, I think you could also use prompt, like this 
`var person = prompt("Please enter your name", "");` and you will have in the var `person` your name.

Comment: Yeaa but i wan't it to be more like a console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing it like so:

```
document.getElementById("enterInput").addEventListener("click", getInput );

function getInput() {
    var val = document.getElementById("inputLine").value;
    //do something with val
    document.getElementById("inputLine").value="";
    return val;
}
```

See [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/nygbLdmL/)

---

Or to fetch it as a variable with `getInput()`:

```
document.getElementById("enterInput").addEventListener("click", function(event){
    var val = getInput();
    alert(val);
});

function getInput() {
    var val = document.getElementById("inputLine").value;
    document.getElementById("inputLine").value="";
    return val;
}
```

See [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/nygbLdmL/1/)

Comment: But how will this work if i wan't my function to be called like a variable

fx. var playerName=getInput();?

Comment: And why is there a e in the getInput(e)?

Comment: oh its not necessary--it just refers to the click event object. I edited it out so you can call it like a variable and added the return value (`return val;`)

Comment: I altered [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nygbLdmL/1/) to demonstrate. Note that `return` calls must come after any code you want to execute.

Comment: But if i do i like this:

var playerName=getInput();
It won't wait to set the variable to whatever you write.

Sorry if i sound like a douchebag, just saw how arrogant i looked.

Comment: I assumed that's why it was attached to the button click event--see the second demo. And I didn't think you sounded like a douchebag lol

Comment: But how do i get it to wait to set the variable, until the player has clicked #enterInput, right now it does it the second the funtion is called.

Comment: See the second demo, it;s being set in the button click event handler